# Access USB drive on Ubuntu Server VM

Tags: server, 18.04, usb, virtualbox, .desktop

I've had a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160273/access-usb-drive-on-ubuntu-server#), but it doesn't solve the problem.

I have the following configuration:

```
Host: Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop
Guest: Ubuntu 18.04 Server
VM Software: VirtualBox
USB Drive: 500GB
```

I have connected the USB drive to the host and configured the guest as follows:

[image]

I then bootup the guest and type `lsblk`, but can't see the USB drive:

[image]

If instead I try to select the USB drive after booting into the guest as follows by deselecting the USB drive option which I had selected in the very first screenshot below:

[image]

I can then temporarily see the drive via the command `lsblk`:

[image]

But then, after a few moments, I get the following error messages and the drive then disappears from `lsblk`:

[image]

**Question:** How do I configure this so the guest sees the host connected USB drive as if the drive was physically connected to the guest itself?

**Aim:** To run bitcoind from the VM and access the full blockchain which is saved on the external host connected USB drive.

Comment: Have you installed *Guest Additions*? If so, try changing the USB controller to USB 3 (must be done while the VM is down). Next, run *Gparted* and see if the device is showing up; maybe it just needs to be mounted.

Comment: @ajgringo619, virtualbox-guest-additions is already installed on the host, but not sure how to install it on a desktop-less server based vm.  All the websites I've searched for far assume that the guest vm is a graphical desktop os.

However, I did try `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` within the guest vm itself, but that did not help.

Comment: *Guest Additions* needs to be installed on the VM; it does not require a GUI desktop. The host needs the *Extension Pack*, not *Guest Additions*.

Comment: @ajgringo619, The USB3 option worked... Not sure why, I only have USB2 on my computer which is confusing.  Thanks for the help!